# trying to create new/empty git repo, git doesn't know "init"

Tags: git

`git init` or `git init --bare`

gives me:

```
git init --bare
Usage: git COMMAND [OPTIONS] [TARGET]
git command 'init' not found: commands are:
  add archimport bisect branch checkout cherry-pick clone commit
  count-objects cvsimport diff fetch format-patch log ls-remote
  merge-one-file octopus parse-remote prune pull push rebase relink rename
  repack request-pull reset resolve revert sh-setup status tag verify-tag
```

I just want to create an empty repo to start with.  But I get this error....

ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something is very sick in your git installation.  You should probably remove it and reinstall it from whatever source you originally obtained it from, along with any dependencies.

`git init` is not just core, it is one of the most fundamental parts of the core of git.  Having it not found is ... bad, and there is no reasonable or correct cause for this.

Comment: You're doomed! DOOMED I say!  But in all seriousness @Daniel is right.  If it can't find the init command, something got screwy with your installation, and I wouldn't trust anything else to work correctly.

Comment: correct.  i installed from source.  I finally figured out how to get the yum install to work (our server had no visibility to any git yum packages).  yum solved the prob